# VSTO Word - How to know when footer or header being edited

Tags: c#, ms-word, office365, vsto

I am currently developing an Word AddIn in C#. I want to prevent header and footer being modified using a password. Is there an event when double clicking footer/header or using the ribbon buttons where I could subscribe on?
Is there a way to determine if the footer or header section is being edited?

Comment: I recommend you investigate document protection options in the Word Developer tab, Restriction group of the Ribbon. The corresponding task pane offers two basic approaches: protection of ranges or forms protection. Forms protection will completely block the header/footer, but makes other editing difficult. Range protection is less restrictive, but more difficult to set up as far as the H/F is concerned. I recommend you pursue this in an end-user venue, such as Super User, until you've worked out the options to be implemented in code.

Comment: Word's events are limited and there are none specifically for H/F access. Most events only "look at" the Selection as it was when the event is triggered, not where it lands (WindowBeforeDoubleClick, WindowBeforeSelectionChange). Possibly, you could replace the built-in Ribbon controls with your own, but disabling the direct access via double-click... not so simple. Thus, the approach of using document protection.